# My ListView keeps calling a sort event

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

So I have this ListView:

```
<asp:listview runat="server" ID="listview_search" itemplaceholderid="itemListing" datasourceid="ds_search">
  <LayoutTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="SortByPrice" commandname="Sort" commandargument="price" >Sort by price</asp:LinkButton>
  <div runat="server" id="itemListing"></div>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
     <div class="container profilelistings">
          <div class="row carousel-row">
              <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 slide-row" style="min-height: 100px;">
                   <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide slide-carousel">
                                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                                        <div class="item active">
                                            <asp:Image id="img_car" imageurl='<%# "images/" + Eval("ownerID") + "/" + Eval("photo1") %>' runat="server"></asp:Image>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <div class="slide-content">
                                <h5><%# Eval("make").ToString() + " " + Eval("model") + " (" + Eval("type") + ") "  %></h5>
                                <h5><span class="price"><%# "£ " + Eval("price") %></span></h5>
                            </div>
                                 <div class="slide-footer">
                                    <span class="pull-right buttons">
                                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i> View more info </button>
                                    </span>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:listview>
```

Which uses the ds_search as the DataSourceID, the ds_search is an SQLDataSource and does a load of joins which then in the code I have:

This, which ammends the query according to the input:

```
 protected void makeQuery()
{
    int make = System.Convert.ToInt32(list_make.SelectedValue);
    int model = System.Convert.ToInt32(list_model.SelectedValue);
    int price = System.Convert.ToInt32(list_price.SelectedValue);

    query = ds_search.SelectCommand;

    // If the make is not equal to 1 then..
    if (make != 1)
    {
        // Add this to the query
        query = query + " AND make_id = @make";
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise ammend it to this
        query = query + " AND make_id > 0";
    }

    // If the model is not equal to 1 then..
    if (model != 1)
    {
        // Ammend the query according to this
        query = query + " AND model_id = @model";
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise ammend the query with this
        query = query + " AND model_id > 0";
    }

    // If the price is equal to 1 then..
    if (price == 1)
    {
        query = query + " AND c.price > -1";
    }
    else if (price == 2)
    {
        query = query + " AND c.price BETWEEN 0 AND 1000";
    }
    else if (price == 3)
    {
        query = query + " AND c.price BETWEEN 1000 AND 2500";
    }
    else if (price == 4)
    {
        query = query + " AND c.price BETWEEN 2500 AND 5000";
    }
    else if (price == 5)
    {
        query = query + " AND c.price BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000";
    }
    else if (price == 6)
    {
        query = query + " AND c.price > 10000";
    }

    // Add the query to the dataSource's SelectCommand
    ds_search.SelectCommand = query;

    // If the make is not equal to 1 then..
    if (make != 1)
    {
        // Bind the make parameters
        ds_search.SelectParameters.Add("make", make.ToString());
    }

    if (model != 1)
    {
        ds_search.SelectParameters.Add("model", model.ToString());
    }

    if (type != 1)
    {
        ds_search.SelectParameters.Add("type", type.ToString());
    }

    if (colour != 1)
    {
        ds_search.SelectParameters.Add("colour", colour.ToString());
    }

    if (year != 1)
    {
        ds_search.SelectParameters.Add("year", year.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now I have this, which Binds the dataSource and listView:

```
 protected void BindListView()
{
    ds_search.DataBind();
    listview_search.DataSourceID = null;
    listview_search.DataSource = ds_search;
    listview_search.DataBind();
}
```

Then to call both methods I have done this in my btn_search click event:

```
protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Call the makeQuery method
    makeQuery();
    // Call the BindListView method
    BindListView();
}
```

Okay, so the problem I am having is that when I load the page and click "Sort by price" to trigger the sorting of the price, it sorts the price perfectly either by ASC or DESC, however when I click the btn_Search and then click "Sort By Price" I get this error:

**The ListView 'listview_search' raised event Sorting which wasn't handled.**

However I don't understand why because I don't have the a Sorting event on the listView at all.

Does anyone understand what is going wrong?